# Query to fetch second highest salary from table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write a query to fetch third highest salary from table?

```
cid  salary
--- ------
1    15000
2    20000
3    7000
4    35000
5    60000
```

Comment: select max( salary ) from yourtablename where salary < ( select max( salary ) from yourtablename );

Comment: I got an answer.. select max(salary) from test where salary < (select max(salary) from test where salary < (select max(salary) from test))

Comment: You got it. very good ;)